# Uniform convergence/differentiation and integration of infinite sums

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

It's more of a confusion for me know: in what cases sums of infinite series can't be integrated and differentiated? I understand that e.g.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}
$$

has the remainder term of for $n+1, n+2...$ equal to $\frac{z^{n+1}}{1-z}$, so it does not converge uniformly for $|z|<1$. But nevertheless I can manipulate for $z<1$: 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k z^k = z\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (z^k)
$$

and so on. What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is that, even though the series does not converge uniformly for $|z|<1$, it *does* converge uniformly for $|z|<r$, for any $r<1$. And that is all you need for the usual manipulations.

Comment: I see. What is the difference between $|z|<1$ and $|z|<r<1$?

Comment: @user19821: It doesn’t converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$, but it converges uniformly on $(-r,r)$ for any positive $r<1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: yes, I see that. The question is, why?

Comment: @user19821: I thought that you wanted to know what the difference is, so that’s the question that I answered. I’m not sure what you’re asking now. Are you asking why it converges uniformly on $(-r,r)$ if $0<r<1$?

Comment: The convergence can not be uniformly for $|z|<1$ because the limit function is unbounded on that domain.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: thanks, of course.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: The right notion here is [locally uniform convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) of a sequence of analytic functions.